# knit_hooks and knit_theme don't seem to play nicely with each other

Tags: r, knitr

I'm trying to get knitr to wrap text AND have syntax highlighting.  I can get one or the other to work, but not both. How do I fix this?

Here is an example, The only difference between the two is that knit_hooks$set changes from:

```
knit_hooks$set(par=function(before, options, envir){if (before) par(mar=c(4,4,.1,.1),cex.lab=.95,cex.axis=.9,mgp=c(2,.7,0),tcl=-.3)})
```

to

```
knit_hooks$set(source=listing, output=listing)
```

UPDATE:  From what I can tell, it's because I'm using \begin{lstlisting} to process the code chunks, so any changes that I make to knit_theme aren't effective (they only change the background color, not the text itself), and I need to fiddle around with \lstdefinestyle instead and set colors manually, which isn't *quite* the solution I'm looking for.

### Syntax Highlighting

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Combining knittheme with knithooks}
\author{author}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

<<echo=FALSE>>=
    library(knitr)
    thm <- knit_theme$get("solarized-dark")
    options(width=60)
    listing <- function(x, options) {
        paste("\\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\\ttfamily,breaklines=true]\n", x, "\\end{lstlisting}\n", sep = "")
    }

    #knit_hooks$set(source=listing, output=listing)
    knit_hooks$set(par=function(before, options, envir){if (before) par(mar=c(4,4,.1,.1),cex.lab=.95,cex.axis=.9,mgp=c(2,.7,0),tcl=-.3)})

    knit_theme$set(thm)
@

\begin{document}
\maketitle
<<Test>>=
    years    = 1996:2010 #Check Syntax highlighting
    years[1]+5 #Check that code wraps to fit in between the page margins and doesn't go on and on until you can't read it anymore.
@
\end{document}
```

[image: Syntax highlighting works but the text doesn't wrap.]

### Wrapping Text

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Combining knittheme with knithooks}
\author{author}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

<<echo=FALSE>>=
    library(knitr)
    thm <- knit_theme$get("solarized-dark")
    options(width=60)
    listing <- function(x, options) {
        paste("\\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\\ttfamily,breaklines=true]\n", x, "\\end{lstlisting}\n", sep = "")
    }

    knit_hooks$set(source=listing, output=listing)
    #knit_hooks$set(par=function(before, options, envir){if (before) par(mar=c(4,4,.1,.1),cex.lab=.95,cex.axis=.9,mgp=c(2,.7,0),tcl=-.3)})

    knit_theme$set(thm)
@

\begin{document}
\maketitle
<<Test>>=
    years    = 1996:2010 #Check Syntax highlighting
    years[1]+5 #Check that code wraps to fit in between the page margins and doesn't go on and on until you can't read it anymore.
@
\end{document}
```

[image: Text Wrapping works but syntax highlighting fails]